# Functions that take DataArrays and Arrays as arguments in Julia

Tags: arrays, function, parameters, julia

I'd like to write a function that can take both a DataArray and a standard Array in Julia. Actually, I'd like to write to methods for a function -- one that takes two vector-like structures as parameters and one that takes two matrix-like parameters.

Since Arrays and DataArrays are basically the same, only that a DataArray allows for NA values, I really do not want to write 4 versions of each function, just to incorporate all different combinations of Array and DataArray parameters. Right now, I use the following six (!) functions, to  achieve my goal:

```
function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::Array{T, 1}, coefficients::Array{T, 1})
  try
    return(exp(covariates' * coefficients)[1])
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::Array{T, 2}, coefficients::Array{T, 2})
  try
    return(exp(covariates * coefficients))
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::DataArray{T, 1}, coefficients::DataArray{T, 1})
  try
    return(exp(covariates' * coefficients)[1])
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::DataArray{T, 2}, coefficients::DataArray{T, 2})
  try
    return(exp(covariates * coefficients))
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::Array{T, 1}, coefficients::DataArray{T, 1})
  try
    return(exp(covariates' * coefficients)[1])
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::Array{T, 2}, coefficients::DataArray{T, 2})
  try
    return(exp(covariates * coefficients))
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
  end
end
```

I'm aware that this might be an inefficient way to compute these products, but I also have a general interest regarding how to write functions taking both Arrays and DataArrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `DataArrays` source.  You'll find a number of methods that take combinations of `DataArray` and `Array`.  For example, you could define `function covar_to_intensity{T<:Union(Array{Number,1},DataArray{Number,1})}(covariates::T, coefficients::T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can define methods for `AbstractArray`:

```
function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::AbstractVector{T}, coefficients::AbstractVector{T})
  try
     return exp(covariates * coefficients)
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
   end
end

function covar_to_intensity{T<:Number}(covariates::AbstractMatrix{T}, coefficients::AbstractMatrix{T})
  try
     return exp((covariates' * coefficients)[1])
  catch
    error("Multiplication of covariates and coefficients not possible.")
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, John. I remember trying to use AbstractArray without any luck. Maybe I did something wrong, like using a generic datatype for the arrays that needs to be a subtype of AbstractArray, in the function definition. I'll give it another shot!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your comment, @rickhg12hs. I'll give your suggestion a shot some time!