# Julia: methods and DataArrays.DataArray

Tags: julia

I would like to write a function `fun1` with a DataArrays.DataArray `y` as unique argument. `y` can be either an integer or a float (in vector or in matrix form).

I have tried to follow the suggestions I have found in stackoverflow ([Functions that take DataArrays and Arrays as arguments in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383449/functions-that-take-dataarrays-and-arrays-as-arguments-in-julia)) and in the official documentation (http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/methods/). However, I couldn't write a code enought flexible to deal with the uncertainty around y.

I would like to have something like (but capable of handling numerical DataArrays.DataArray):

```
function fun1(y::Number)
   println(y);
end
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One options can be to define:

```
fun1{T<:Number}(yvec::DataArray{T}) = foreach(println,yvec)
```

Then,

```
using DataArrays
v = DataArray(rand(10))
w = DataArray(rand(1:10,10))
fun1(v)
#
# elements of v printed as Flaot64s
#
fun1(w)
#
# elements of w printed as Ints
#
```

A delicate but recurring point to note is the *invariance* of Julia parametric types which necessitate defining a parametric function. A look at the documentation regarding types should clarify this concept (http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#types).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I will carefully read this part of the official documentation.